# Query to get values from table based on criteria from same table, Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with the following table structure and desired output

```
historical_id grd_id register_type timestamp           address value historical_type insertion_time
         5358      2            11 2016-05-07 12:45:00       1  18.1               1 2016-05-07 13:44:58
         5359      2            11 2016-05-07 12:45:00       2  51.4               1 2016-05-07 13:44:58
         5360      2            11 2016-05-07 12:45:00       3 476                 1 2016-05-07 13:44:58
         5364      2            11 2016-05-07 13:00:00       1  18.79              1 2016-05-07 13:59:58
         5365      2            11 2016-05-07 13:00:00       2  51.2               1 2016-05-07 13:59:58
         5366      2            11 2016-05-07 13:00:00       3 718                 1 2016-05-07 13:59:58
```

Desired output from query

```
kWh_date           temp  rh   co2
2016-05-0712:45:00 18.1  51.4 476 
2016-05-0713:00:00 18.79 51.2 718
```

Can anybody help as to how I get the desired output. I have tried to 'GROUP' by timestamp (not my decision to use this name and cannot change it) but it just shows me 1 set of data (ie 'address' 1). I have used 3 'SELECT' statements but that shows the timestamp repeated. Any help is much appreciated.

I have tried

```
SELECT `register_type`  
     , `timestamp`
     , `address`
     , `value` 
  FROM grdxf.historical 
 WHERE `register_type` = 11 
 GROUP 
    BY `timestamp`;
```

I have tried different queries but they end up failing also. I'm really at a lose and new to queries.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the SQL statement that you have written.

Comment: Could it be that you actually want to `group by timestamp,address` instead of grouping just by timestamp?

Comment: What is that ?.........give relation between the given table structure and its desired output or tell us what you are trying to achieve from the given table structure.

Comment: I don't think so, I want to group the 'values' column from the main table above against the timestamp and end up with 3 different values columns based on the 'address numbers (1,2,3) and one timestamp column. I really hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(900 * FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/900)) timestamp
     , MAX(CASE WHEN address = 1 THEN value END) temp 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN address = 2 THEN value END) rh 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN address = 3 THEN value END) co2 
  FROM historical
 WHERE register_type = 11 
 GROUP 
    BY timestamp;
```

Comment: Thank you Strawberry, changed your query slightly and it worked. Not sure this is going to be readable but this is what I changed........SELECT `timestamp`
     , MAX(CASE WHEN address = 1 THEN `value` END) temp 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN address = 2 THEN `value` END) rh 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN address = 3 THEN `value` END) co2 
  FROM grdxf.historical
 WHERE register_type = 11 
 GROUP 
    BY timestamp;